# Importing content-only package to DotNet Core 3.1 project in Visual Studio 16.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-spec

I have defined and created a content-only package to share JSON schemas between different projects. I packaged it using `nuget.exe`, and could successfully add it to .Net Framework 4.6 library project.

But when I tried to add it to the DotNet Core 3.1 library project (NUnit tests) the following error occurred:

```
NU1212 Invalid project-package combination for <package name>. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type
```

Nuget support documentation ([package type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/set-package-type), [content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files)) does not list any restrictions (beyond "assuming they are compatible") on the content-only packages. Question is how do I create DotNet Core 3.1 library compatible content-only Nuget package?

I tried disabling all data sources except the local one as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527004/how-to-fix-nu1212-for-dotnet-tool-install), but that didn't make any difference.

Here is a `.nuspec` file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Package.JsonSchemas</id>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <packageTypes>
            <packageType name="Dependency" />
        </packageTypes>
        <authors>me</authors>
        <owners>me</owners>
        <releaseNotes>Fill in later</releaseNotes>
        <description>Set of JSON schemas.</description>
        <tags>json, json-schema, tdv</tags>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="JsonSchemas\*.json" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="content\JsonSchemas" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Schema example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",

  "$defs": {
    "ArrayItem": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },

  "title": "dataset object",
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "Data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/ArrayItem"
      },
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "required": [ "Data" ]
}
```

Comment: Please use them in your nuspec file:  `<files><file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="content\JsonSchemas" /> <file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any" /></files>`

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? If that guy's answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to mark it:)

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT, I did as you and _thatguy_ recommended. I even just copy and pasted the nuspec definition from _thatguy's_ answer and I still get the same error message in Visual Studio (now 16.7).

Comment: Two more suggestions: first try to use the latest [nuget.exe cli v5.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to pack the project. Second, before you install the new version of the project, you should make sure that your project is already removed it---do a clean step. Then, [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

Comment: Yes, thank you, clearing all Nuget caches first and then reinstalling the package helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NU1212` error does point to `dotnet tool install`, it does not seem to be caused by your package directly. Are you sure that your are adding your package correctly via the NuGet package manager or [console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli)? It is not reproducible in a .NET Core 3.1 library or NUnit project type.

As @Perry Qian-MSFT suggested, you should always make sure that the old NuGet package is removed completely before you add a new one, especially if you did not change the package version in the NuSpec. It is a common issue that the old, cached package is used instead. To [clear all NuGet package caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) use one of the following commands.

- In `dotnet.exe` use `locals --clear all`
- In `nuget.exe` use `locals -clear all`
- In Visual Studio >= 2017 go to *Tools* > *NuGet Package Manager* > *Package Manager Settings* and click  *Clear All NuGet Cache(s)*

> Question is how do I create DotNet Core 3.1 library compatible content-only Nuget package?

NuGet 4.0+ with `PackageReference` uses `contentFiles`, see this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files).

> Content files are included in a package using the  element, specifying the content folder in the target attribute. However, **such files are ignored** when the package is installed in a project using **PackageReference**, which instead uses the  element.

You can keep copying the files to the `content` directory for compatibility, but you have to copy them to the `contentFiles` directory, too. You have to make sure that they are located under `contentFiles\any\any\`, otherwise they will not be extracted to projects with any target framework.

```
<file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\JsonSchemas" />
```

The path within the package is given below, so the first path segment represents the code language, the second the target framework moniker. You have to use `any` in boh cases.

```
/contentFiles/{codeLanguage}/{TxM}
```

Below is your sample NuSpec adapted to `contentFiles` that will also work in .NET Core 3.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Package.JsonSchemas</id>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <authors>me</authors>
        <owners>me</owners>
        <releaseNotes>Fill in later</releaseNotes>
        <description>Set of JSON schemas.</description>
        <tags>json, json-schema, tdv</tags>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="any\any\JsonSchemas\*.json" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="content\JsonSchemas" />
        <file src="JsonSchemas\*.*" target="contentFiles\any\any\JsonSchemas" />
    </files>
</package>
```

From the same [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/set-package-type) that you linked, it is recommended not to specify the dependency type explicitly for backwards compatibility, so I left it out.

> Package types are set in the .nuspec file. It's best for backwards compatibility to **not explicitly set the Dependency type** and to instead rely on NuGet assuming this type when no type is specified.

Comment: A note to people who read through @thatguy answer, used updated example and still got the same issue. Try [clearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) Nuget caches before adding updated package, as 'Perry Qian-MSFT' suggested above.

Comment: @GKalnytskyi Thank you for your comment. I have added a section about clearing the NuGet caches.